# How to call jquery method in different page event like pageload, ispostback, page refresh, onsubmit

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, events

In my master page i am calling the jquery method on pageload event. It will do some truncation operation in sharepoint page. The problem is, if i have add new item to the sharepoint form and if i submit the form,My page got postback(refreshed) so the jquery method not called.
* After submiting the form, If i reload the page its working properly.

Is there any way to call the jquery method in different event?.
How to resolvet the issue.

The below jquery only i am using in my page.
[Jquery](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/Truncate-text-in-list-view-and-add-mouseover-preview.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pageload isn't always the right answer and without knowing the JQuery code and what it's doing with what elements at what time, I'd suggest having a look at [This Explanation](http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same). Personally I find that using the

`$(document).ready(function () {

});`

Always seems to work for me in SharePoint.